# create a post in Wordpress with an external script

Tags: wordpress

I am making a java script to create a few posts in a Wordpress blog by only inserting them into the wp_posts so table. So far I could browse the posts on web browser. Question is, is it good enough with the db operations ? does anyone know any other subsequent tables need to be updated for making a post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up adding REST API V2 plugin and make calls to it for creating all sorts of things. Worked like a champ

Answer (score 1):

Not really, you can extend the default and existing WordPress posts.

But you can go ahead and create your own table like: https://github.com/wp-plugins/wordpress-guest-post/blob/master/wordpressguestpost.php